# Spring Boot model parameter lost when redirect

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have a controller with 2 methods. I want the first one to redirect to the second one, saving 2 attributes in the model. The second methods cannot read one of the two attributes. "logged" is True in both methods, "username" is null in the second one.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doLogin(Model model, @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, RedirectAttributes re) throws IOException {
    
    boolean logged = elasticSearchConnector.checkCredentials(username, password, context);
    
    model.addAttribute("logged", logged); 
    System.out.println(model.getAttribute("logged"));  //True

    
    if(logged) {
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        System.out.println(model.getAttribute("username"));  //amedeo
        return "redirect:/getAccountFragment";
    }
    else {
    model.addAttribute("loginError", "Incorrect Login Credentials");
    return String.format("fragments/login-fragment :: content(url='%s')", "/?lang=en");
    }
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/getAccountFragment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAccountFragment(Model model) throws IOException, ParseException {

System.out.println(model.getAttribute("logged"));  //True

    if(!model.containsAttribute("logged")) {
        return String.format("fragments/login-fragment :: content(url='%s')", "/?lang=en");
    }
    else {
    if(!(boolean)model.getAttribute("logged")) {
        return String.format("fragments/login-fragment :: content(url='%s')", "/?lang=en");
    }
    else {
        String username = (String) model.getAttribute("username");
        
        System.out.println(model.getAttribute("username"));  //null
    }
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [RedirectAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html), like:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doLogin(Model model, @RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
    
    boolean logged = elasticSearchConnector.checkCredentials(username, password, context);
    
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("logged", logged);
    
    if (logged) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("username", username);
        return "redirect:/getAccountFragment";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("loginError", "Incorrect Login Credentials");
        return String.format("fragments/login-fragment :: content(url='%s')", "/?lang=en");
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAccountFragment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAccountFragment(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException, ParseException {

    if (!model.containsAttribute("logged")) {
        return String.format("fragments/login-fragment :: content(url='%s')", "/?lang=en");
    } else {
        if (!(boolean)model.getAttribute("logged")) {
            return String.format("fragments/login-fragment :: content(url='%s')", "/?lang=en");
        } else {
            String username = (String) model.getAttribute("username");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope my solution helped you @amadeo-pachera